# Getting nil exception when reading from UIPasteboard, iOS 9

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipasteboard

I'm trying to read the recent string that was copied in the clipboard. I'm not facing a problem when I'm the "copy" happenes in the app, but the point of my app is read the last text copied when the application is in the background. I'm doing continuous check every 0.5 second for the value of

> UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().changeCount

to detect if a new item is there in the clipboard. But When I'm trying to print that, I get a nil exception.

This is detection code in my timer:

```
  if(self.count != UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().changeCount)
            {

                let currentPasteboardContents  = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string

                NSLog("content is %@",currentPasteboardContents!);

                self.count=UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().changeCount

            }
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I tried to search for a solution, and the closest one that I went through is that I think that I need Request Full Access in the Info.plist

I did add these lines to my info.plist and I'm still having the same error:

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>RequestsOpenAccess</key>
        <string>Yes</string>
    </dict>
```

Any hints please where to fix this problem?

Thanks ,,,

Comment: `if let currentPasteboardContents  = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string { print(currentPasteboardContents) }`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've tried to use your line of code. There is no string printed though. The timer detect that there is a change in the count of the clipboard but I can' read the data.

Comment: yes that means your `UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string` gives you nil

Comment: Yes, but I'm copying a text outside the application when it's in the background, and I want to read that copied text. thanks

Comment: it's working well, when I'm copying within and inside the application.

Comment: Why do you use a Timer, there is a notification for this noh?

Comment: well, I don't know about the notification, but it's the same, I'm detecting if there is a new text in the clipboard,  my problem is that I can't access it !